# Perl Script for Email validation?

Tags: perl, validation, scripting, ubuntu-12.04, email-validation

I've created a perl script to validate email ids for my marketing team to send campaigns.

The script is behaving  erratically.

For Example, I had validated 135 email ids on various dates,

```
******************************************
Date   |    Valid     | Invalid  | Total
******************************************
23-Dec-13    45       |   90     | 135
******************************************
24-Dec-13    90       |   45     | 135
******************************************
25-Dec-13    133      |   02     | 135
******************************************
```

I'm unable to figure out where it went wrong,

[Link to code](https://github.com/bcrajkumar/techstuff/commit/8af92f1c60c7da6eddd4fa2f9705a87e52b25692)

Code:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 use Data::Dumper;

 %lookup_cache = ();

 sub valid_address {
   my($addr) = @_;
   my($domain, $valid);

   # Lower-case address
   $addr = lc($addr);

   # Validate format of address
   return(0) unless ($addr =~ /^[^@]+@([-\w]+\.)+[a-z]{2,4}$/);

   # Grab domain
   $domain = (split(/@/, $addr))[1];

   # Lookup and return cached result if it exists
   $cached_result = $lookup_cache{$domain};
   if ($cached_result ne '')
   {
     #print "[cached_result] ";
     return $cached_result;
   }

   # Do domain lookup
   $valid = 0;
   if (open(DNS, "nslookup -q=any $domain |"))
   {
     while (<DNS>) {
       $valid = 1 if (/^$domain.*\s(mail exchanger|internet address)\s=/i);
     }
   }

   # Store cached result for later
   $lookup_cache{$domain} = $valid;

   return $valid;
 }

 while (<>) {
   $addy = $_;
   $addy =~ s/\s+$//;
   if ($addy)
   {
     print "$addy " . (valid_address($addy) ? 'valid' : 'invalid') . "\n";
   }
 }
```

Comment: Without the script, no one will be able to tell you what is wrong with your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using `strict` and `warnings` in all Perl scripts.

Ask for mail exchanger records with `nslookup -q=MX` to make the script stable. The output of `nslookup -q=any` **might** include the MX record but not always (I suppose it returns *any* record type it finds, not necessarily MX?).

**Edit:** This script works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %lookup_cache = ();

sub valid_address {
  my($addr) = @_;
  my($domain, $valid);

  # Lower-case address
  $addr = lc($addr);

  # Validate format of address
  return(0) unless ($addr =~ /^[^@]+@([-\w]+\.)+[a-z]{2,4}$/);

  # Grab domain
  $domain = (split(/@/, $addr))[1];

  # Lookup and return cached result if it exists
  my $cached_result = $lookup_cache{$domain};
  if (defined $cached_result)
  {
    return $cached_result;
  }

  # Do domain lookup
  $valid = 0;
  if (open(DNS, "nslookup -q=MX $domain |"))
  {
    while (<DNS>) {
      $valid = 1 if (/^$domain.*\s(mail exchanger|internet address)\s=/i);
    }
  }

  # Store cached result for later
  $lookup_cache{$domain} = $valid;

  return $valid;
}

while (<>) {
  my $addy = $_;
  $addy =~ s/\s+$//;
  if ($addy)
  {
    print "$addy " . (valid_address($addy) ? 'valid' : 'invalid') . "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: @alest_t If a line did not match the regex, $valid will remain unchanged. However, breaking early makes sense because remaining lines need not be checked.

Comment: @Gowtham thanks, good point. I don't know what I was thinking :)

Comment: I made changes as per your suggestion, The results all are showing invalid. Is there anything to add??

# Do domain lookup
  $valid = 0;
  if (open(DNS, "nslookup -q=Mx"))
  {
    while (<DNS>) {
      $valid = 1 if (/^$domain.*\s(mail exchanger|internet address)\s=/i);
    }
  }

Comment: What happens when you run `nslookup -q=MX` with one of your email addresses on the command line?

Comment: bcrajkumar@localhost:~$ nslookup -q=Mx arun@gmail.com
Server:         192.168.1.1
Address:        192.168.1.1#53

** server can't find arun@gmail.com: NXDOMAIN

Actually I've configured 192.168.1.1 local router address as DNS/Gateway for my system

Comment: Sorry -- I meant domains. E.g. `nslookup -q=MX gmail.com` will surely include the string "mail exchanger".

Answer (score 2):

Email address syntax can be [quite complicated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Syntax). So, validation could be tricky - very easy to go wrong. I suggest exploring a proper library on CPAN.

[Email::Valid](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Email-Valid-1.192/lib/Email/Valid.pm) seems to support domain checks and TLD checks too.
**Disclaimer**: I have not used this module personally but it seems to be actively maintained.

The output of nslookup might have changed between multiple runs of the script, so your script might be reporting inconsistent results. I would suggest adding more log statements so that you can pin point what is going on.